# How to convert a URLFetch to a URLRead or URLExecute?

Tags: programming, web-access

Consider the following function:

```
 URLFetch[
    "https://developers.betfair.com/api.betfair.com/exchange/betting/\
  json-rpc/v1",
    {"StatusCode", "Headers", "Content"},
    "Body" -> json,
    Method -> "POST",
    "Headers" -> {"X-Application" -> DEVKEY, 
    "X-Authentication" -> TOKEN}]
```

Wolfram advises to use URLRead or URLExecute as from v 11.0 onwards.

What would be the URLRead / URLExecute version of the above given URLFetch?

Comment: I don't use these so I don't know, but `HTTPRequest` seems to have all the options you're using here.  It goes inside `URLRead`.  The result object has multiple pieces of data in it that you can extract (try `result = URLRead[...]; result["Properties"]`).

Comment: I "trial / error-ed" quite a bit with a HTTPRequest inside a URLRead but didn't get it to work. Probably a small issue...

Comment: @niloderoock could you provide a working URLFetch example to have something testable?